# Regex is returning undesired results

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to capture a group from regex that will follow this pattern:

Ex1 - `anyanyany` group 1 have to be `anyanyany`

Ex2 - `anyanyany.abcany` group 1 have to be `anyanyany`

Ex3 - `anyany.abcde.fghi` group 1 have to be `anyany.abcde`

When I try `(.+)(?:\.)`, it only returns Ex2 and Ex3. If I change it for `(.+)(?:\.)*` it returns the same string of input.

I really don't know what I have to do to solve it. Someone could help me? Which knowledgement I am missing?

[https://regex101.com/r/jG6wY8/2](https://www.regex101.com/r/uW7iB7/2)

Comment: Why you don't simply search for last character '.' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this non-greedy regex.

```
(.+?)(?:\.[^.]*)?$
```

In java you need to escape the backslash one more time, so it would be like,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(?:\\.[^.]*)?$");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eK2aF2/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^([^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)?)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX3rX1/2)

**PS:** Used `^([^.\n]+(?:\.[^.\n]+)?)` in [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX3rX1/2) since demo has multiple inputs in different lines.

Comment: If the idea is to grab all but the last dot plus letters, then your regex fails with abc.def.ghi.jkl, i.e., it returns only abc.def, and I dislike the \n in there - what's its purpose?

Comment: Idea was to grab string with one or two dots. So yes it will match `abc.def` from `abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno.pqr`

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the answer (+1). But it won't work.

Comment: If we put `anyanyany.abcany` as input, the output would be `anyanyany`. But it is returning `anyanyany.abcany`

Comment: Well you can see that question wasn't clear that you want to match all but last string after dot.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a regex to capture the wanted part, eliminate the unwanted part:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.[^.]+$","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex patterns in order to match your criterias:

- If you were supposed to match the first two words tokenized by a dot: `^([^\.]+)(?:\.[^\.]+)?$|(?:([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)\.)`

  `a => a
   a.b => a
   a.b.c => a.b
   a.b.c.d => a.b`
- If you were supposed to match every words tokenized by a dot, but not the last token: `^([^\.]+)(?:\.[^\.]+)?$|(?:([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)\.)`

  `a => a
   a.b => a
   a.b.c => a.b
   a.b.c.d => a.b.c`

Comment: You don't have to escape the dot (.) between  [ and  ]. And the regex fails to match a.b.c.d

Comment: @laune: I have edited my response in order to accomplish your comments.